# Why does the WebView in my Mac app behave differently from Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, swift, macos, wkwebview

I couldn't find an answer on MDN Web Docs and Stack Overflow, Google Search so I'm posting a question.

The issue I'm experiencing is that...

**Why does the 'playbackRate Change' button in the provided 'controls' of the HTML Audio attribute not work in my macOS project's WebView?**

I have a very simple HTML that plays audio.

```html
<audio src="../Audio/013.mp3" controls="controls" style="width:370px;position: absolute;top:560px;left:200px;"></audio>
```

In Safari, the buttons supported in Controls work fine. However, in my Mac app, the playback speed change button doesn't work.

Just like this

#Safari
[image]

# my Mac App
[image]

Deployment Target and Minimum Deployments macOS -> `12.0`

Please note that it only supports macOS apps.

I have tried.

```swift
webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true 
webView.configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true 
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .audio
```

App Sandbox -> `outgoing Connections (Client)` Check

++

As an additional test, the playbackRate functionality itself works, but the button remains inactive.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really foolishly tried to solve the problem elsewhere. The root of the problem was that I inherited WKWebView to prevent right-clicking and had a statement in willOpenMenu to removeAll items. I never thought this would have any impact on the issue I was facing, and I'm fortunate to have found it now. I won't delete the question as other developers may have similarly challenging experiences.

```
class CustomWKWebView: WKWebView {
    override func willOpenMenu(_ menu: NSMenu, with event: NSEvent) {
#warning("here??")
        menu.items.removeAll() // -> is this criminal !!!!!
    }
```